# How do I set and get updated Environment Variables in WIX Installer?

Tags: batch-file, wix

I am using WIX installer.

At one step in the installation I want to ask user the Admin Password and then Set the Environment variable ADM_PASSWD with the user given value. Later in the next step I will run a .bat file to setup IIS server and for that I need this ADM_PASSWD.

I know running a .bat file is not a good idea and this whole thing is a mess but trust me I have no choice.

I am able to set the variable and in C# code when I read it, I am getting right value.

WIX Code:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetEnvVariableProperty" 
                  Property="ADM_PASSWD" 
                  Value="[PASSWORD]" />

<CustomAction Id="SetEnvVariable" 
                  Return="check" 
                  Execute="immediate" 
                  BinaryKey="CustomActions.dll"
                  DllEntry="SetEnvVariable" />



    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CheckLicense" Before="InstallFinalize" />

          <Custom Action="SetEnvVariableProperty" After="InstallFinalize"/>
      <Custom Action="SetEnvVariable" Before="InstallFinalize"/>

      <Custom Action="RunIISBat" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>


 <CustomAction Id="RunIISBat"    
                  FileKey="filERSDRC087ADD4D68354E59268F31A3"
                  ExeCommand="&quot;c:\Program Files (x86)\App Location\&quot;"
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="asyncWait"
                  Impersonate="no"
                  />
```

C#Code :

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetEnvVariable(Session session)
{
      session.Log("Setting Environement Variable");
      String envName = "ADM_PASSWD";
      string envValue = session["ADM_PASSWD"].ToString();

      // Determine whether the environment variable exists.
      if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envName) == null)
      {
          session.Log(envName + " Does not exist !");
          // If it doesn't exist, create it.
          Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envName, envValue);
          session.Log("Setting ADM PASSWD To : " + envValue);
          session.Log(envName + " created !");
      }

         session.Log(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envName).ToString());
         session.Log("Done Setting Environement Variable");
         return  ActionResult.Success;
}
```

But somehow my .bat file is not getting that variable. I don't know if it gets deleted or something?

Comment: Why not pass the admin password as a argument to the bat file through a custom action?

Comment: Because there are other scripts which use that env variable and I can't change all of them.